# Fill NAs with numerical sequence by group

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, na, data-wrangling

I'd like to uniquely fill NAs with a numerical sequence by group.

Here is a minimal data set:

```r
d
#>    id year
#> 1   1 1998
#> 2   1 1999
#> 3   1 2001
#> 4   1   NA
#> 5   1   NA
#> 6   2 1997
#> 7   2 1999
#> 8   2 2001
#> 9   2   NA
#> 10  2   NA
#> 11  3 1997
#> 12  3 1998
#> 13  3 1999
#> 14  3 2000
#> 15  3 2001

#data set
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), year = structure(list(year = c(1997L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, NA, 1998L, 1999L, 2001L, NA, NA, 1998L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
))), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

NAs should be replaced by a non-already-taken value of the numerical sequence 1997 to 2001; so that the resulted data frame looks like this:

```
#>    id year
#> 1   1 1997
#> 2   1 1998
#> 3   1 1999
#> 4   1 2000
#> 5   1 2001
#> 6   2 1997
#> 7   2 1998
#> 8   2 1999
#> 9   2 2000
#> 10  2 2001
#> 11  3 1997
#> 12  3 1998
#> 13  3 1999
#> 14  3 2000
#> 15  3 2001

#data set
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), year = c(1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
2001L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R alternative:

```r
d$year2 <- ave(d$year, d$id, FUN = function(z) { z[is.na(z)] <- setdiff(1997:2001, z); z;})
d
#    id year year2
# 1   1 1998  1998
# 2   1 1999  1999
# 3   1 2001  2001
# 4   1   NA  1997
# 5   1   NA  2000
# 6   2 1997  1997
# 7   2 1999  1999
# 8   2 2001  2001
# 9   2   NA  1998
# 10  2   NA  2000
# 11  3 1997  1997
# 12  3 1998  1998
# 13  3 1999  1999
# 14  3 2000  2000
# 15  3 2001  2001
```

`ave` is a simple function to do operations on a vector (first arg) based on grouping criteria (a `list`-like second arg).  The function is given a single vector of values for one group at a time, so with this data the anon-func is called three times. The only gotcha with `ave` is that `ave` always coerces the function's return value to be the same class as the input vector, which can be frustrating and nonsensical (I'm sure there was reason for that behavior at some point).

Knowing that `z` at any one time is all of `year` for one group at a time, the inner workings of that function are simple: replace all `NA` values with the values missing from `1997:2001`. This has a huge caveat, though: this presumes that the only legitimate values in `z` are `c(NA, 1997:2001)`; if there is ever something else, this may very fail/explode or cause your neighbor's car to mis-fire.

In that sense, this method is a little fragile. To be more resilient, we'd likely need to have some allowances. For instance, is it okay to leave values outside of `1997:2001` in the data, or should they be replaced as well? If not, then is there a heuristic for determining which of the missing values are imputed into the `NA` values?

---

Data

```r
d <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), year = c(1998L, 1999L, 2001L, NA, NA, 1997L, 1999L, 2001L, NA, NA, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: Even though I must admit I don't fully understand the code, this answer works fine with my (much more complex) data set. Thanks!

Comment: I added a little dialog to the answer, hope it provides some context.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
d$year <- coalesce(prodNA(d[2],noNA=0.3)$year, d$year)
```

---

If it needs to be grouped by

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(year = coalesce(prodNA(cur_data()["year"], noNA = 0.3)$year, year)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 2
      id  year
   <int> <int>
 1     1  1997
 2     1  1998
 3     1  1999
 4     1  2000
 5     1  2001
 6     2  1997
 7     2  1998
 8     2  1999
 9     2  2000
10     2  2001
11     3  1997
12     3  1998
13     3  1999
14     3  2000
15     3  2001
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3,each=5),
       year = rep(1997:2001,3))
```

Comment: I always forget about this one function... Thanks!

Comment: What would be a solution by group though?

Comment: @Maël updated the post

Comment: Thanks, but it actually does not work on my data set... What data are you using?

Comment: @Maël I updated the data i used.  I didn't use the `d$year<- prodNA(d[2],noNA=0.3);
d<-arrange(d,id,year)`in your data.  The reason is that you are updating the `year` column in the original data with the new 'year' and thus the original 'year' is not available

Comment: Sorry. I can’t access the data anymore. But i will I answer tomorrow (in about 14 hours).

Comment: It indeed works, but then I specifically added the part `d$year<- prodNA(d[2],noNA=0.3); d<-arrange(d,id,year)` because that is how my data set is arranged and that adds another layer of complexity. How you would you do it knowing `d` is like in the question?

Comment: @Maël As I mentioned earlier, you are updating the `year` with `prodNA`, the way is to add a new column `d$year1 <- prodNA(d[2],noNA=0.3)` and then use the `arrange` and group_by

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time. @r2evans answer works fine, so I am accepting his answer.

Comment: @Maël Thanks for that.  I was sure that it is going to happen.  So, my judgement was correct

Comment: In any case, I changed the data generation process to avoid the misunderstanding we had.

Comment: I guess your initial input data didn't show any NAs